# My Subject is not working properly in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I've created a subject in service file as usual

```
editLectures = new Subject<Lecture>();

getEditLectureListener() {
  return this.editLectures.asObservable();
}
```

From one component I'm sending a data (I am getting proper data when I `console.log` it)

```
onUpdate(lec: any) {
  this.attendanceService.emitLecture(lec);
}
```

On another component I'm listening to the Subject:

```
this.updateLecture = this.attendanceService.getEditLectureListener().subscribe(result => {
  // my code
  // on console.log(result) i am not getting anything and other listeners
  // are working perfectly, the only difference is that
  // its not emitting data from http response 
});
```

In service I'm emitting the data:

```
emitLecture(lec: Lecture) {
  this.editLectures.next(lec);
  this.router.navigate(['edit-lecture']);
}
```

Comment: Define "not working properly"? What does that mean? What do you observe? What is expected?

Comment: not getting anything while listening to the subject where i want to receive the data

Answer (score 9):

You need to use BehaviorSubject instead of Subject so the last emitted value will be available for new subscriber (when your listener component is instantiated).

```
editLectures = new BehaviorSubject<Lecture>(null);
```

Comment: It'd suggest `ReplaySubject(1)` instead, you don't really need to store the last value, just be able to pass it to new subscribers.