# Subject not returning anything

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm having trouble with **Subject** on Angular.

On my service I have `formSendStatus = new Subject<boolean>();`

I have a *form.component* that will set the next value for that subject like this: `myservice.formSendStatus.next(true)`;

Then, I have another component that subscribes to it:

```
ngOnInit() {
   myservice.formSendStatus.subscribe(
      data => console.log(data)
   );
}
```

I get nothing on the console. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sounds good be sure that you subscribe before next is called.

Comment: Do you imediatly execute `next()` int `onInit()` of your service? i would suspect a timing issue. please provide a stackblitz with your problem

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58935881/my-subject-is-not-working-properly-in-angular/58935980#58935980

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you shouldn't subscribe to `formSendStatus` instead of that you should to subscribe to a property that is observable of `formSendStatus` like this:

```
export class MyService {
   formSendStatus: Subject<boolean>;
   formSend$: Observable<boolean>;
   constructor() {
     this.formSendStatus = new Subject<boolean>();
     this.formSend$ = this.formSendStatus.asObservable();
   }
}
```

Then in your component you should do this:

```
ngOnInit() {
   myservice.formSend$.subscribe(
      data => console.log(data)
   );
}
```

Now every time that you emit a value with `next()` in `formSendStatus` the component will know by the observable `formSend$`

Comment: This is a good practice, not actually a problem though. Subjects are also observable a.

Comment: Hey Thank you! Good to know! I ended up doing a BehaviourSubject but I'm definitely keeping that in mid next time. Thanks again!

Comment: Your welcome. In fact, BehaviorSubject extends Subject, so you can change ```Subject``` to ```BehaviorSubject``` in my answer and it going to work too. Of course, take in count that ```BehaviorSubject``` save the last value and if it already has a value saved when a new component subscribes to the ```formSend$``` immediately it's going to receive the last value saved in the  ```BehaviorSubject```. Then each time a value is emitted with `` next``, they will receive that new value.

Answer (score 1):

When using a subject, you have to call next() on it for it to emit a value. In the case of a plain subject (which you’re using here), you need to make sure you’re already subscribed when next is called. If thats not possible, you may use a BehaviorSubject or a ReplaySubject since they will cache values and emit them to new subscribers.

```
formSendStatus = new ReplaySubject<boolean>(1) // the number is the number of values to cache, 1 means only store and emit the last value, no number means store and cache all values

formSendStatus = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false); // behavior subjects require a default value, in this case false is the default value
```